# Range of multivariable function $z=e^{x+y} \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I would like to know the range the multivariable function 
$$z=e^{x+y} \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$

I think the range of e is all positive numbers excluding zero and arctan is would be  between $\frac{-\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$. So adding them together we would have all numbers between 0 and $\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Another possibility that crossed my mind is all positive numbers excluding zeros.

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Well we need that

$$
\frac{-\pi}2 < \frac yx < \frac{\pi}2
$$

Because of the arctangent, the exponential accepts any number.

If you multiply with $2x$ you get

$$
-x\pi < 2y < x\pi
$$

This can be changed into a single inequality by making all the $x$ and $y$ absolute values, you can check that the following is equvalent to the above by doing the cases with the absolute value.

$$
2\cdot|\:\!y| < \pi\cdot|x|
$$

The range is then simple the set of all pairs $(x,y)$ such that the inequality is true, which is written as

$$
\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\:\::\:\:2\cdot|\:\!y| < \pi\cdot|x|\}
$$

This looks something like
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify your answer?

Comment: @AaSa Which part of the answer is not clear?

Comment: How to re-rewrite it and he expression {(x,y)∈ℝ2:2⋅|y|<π⋅|x|}

Comment: @AaSa I've attempted to clarify what I did, please tell me if anythings still not clear.

Comment: why x/y between π/2 and -π/2? Isn't z which is the arctan between is between π/2 and -π/2?